# How to edit the capabilities with python when publishing map services

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy

Publishing map service the normal way is done [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=07l7Thl1tV8) using arcgis desktop.

But I decided to do it with python so I can automate the process or something like that but first off I need to edit some of the info according to [this](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s30000006q000000), you would create the SD file before publishing. 
Due to the 0 rep I can't post more then two links but normal publishing [image: normal publishing]

and using arcpy

[image: using arcpy].

As you can see I highlighted the description according to the image does it means it is searching for the Item Description.

Is the the right way of doing it

```
# find the Item Information Description element 
Capability= doc.getElementsByTagName('Capabilities')
for item in Capability:
    if item.parentNode.tagName == 'FeatureAccess':
       #How do i check this check box?
    else:
```

Answer (score 2):

The tag you want to be looking for is 'TypeName'.

you can access it like this:

```
import xml.dom.minidom as dom

def feature_server_toggle(doc, status):
    type_names = doc.getElementsByTagName('TypeName')
    for type_name in type_names:
        if type_name.firstChild.data == "FeatureServer" and status.lower() == 'on':
            type_name.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("Enabled")[0].firstChild.data = "true"
        if type_name.firstChild.data == "FeatureServer" and status.lower() == 'off':
            type_name.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("Enabled")[0].firstChild.data = "false"

sddraft = <path/to/sddraft>
output = <path/to/output>
doc = dom.parse(sddraft)

with open(output, 'w+') as xml:
    feature_server_toggle(doc, 'on')
    doc.writexml(xml)
```

Or you could alter the function to allow it to enable or disable any capability like so:

```
import xml.dom.minidom as dom

def capability_toggle(doc, server_type, status):
    type_names = doc.getElementsByTagName('TypeName')
    for type_name in type_names:
        if type_name.firstChild.data == "{}".format(server_type) and status.lower() == 'on':
            type_name.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("Enabled")[0].firstChild.data = "true"
        if type_name.firstChild.data == "{}".format(server_type) and status.lower() == 'off':
            type_name.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("Enabled")[0].firstChild.data = "false"

sddraft = <path/to/sddraft>
output = <path/to/output>
doc = dom.parse(sddraft)

with open(output, 'w+') as xml:
    capability_toggle(doc, 'FeatureServer', 'on')
    capability_toggle(doc, 'KmlServer', 'off')
    doc.writexml(xml)
```

Here is a list of valid values to use for server_type:

- ‘KmlServer’
- ‘FeatureServer’
- ‘MapServer’
- ‘WCSServer’
- ‘WMSServer’
- ‘WFSServer’
- ‘SchematicsServer’
- ‘MobileServer’
- ‘NAServer’

Answer (score 0):

Okay this is something new and the simnple solution to this is save a Service Draft file and open up with a text editor. Next you are able to search for the capabilities you want to change for example the Feature Access which I wanted was called the

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBspF.png)